# How to run c programs continuously as background process in ubuntu

Tags: c, process, ubuntu-16.04

Hi I have small c program to add two numbers as below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
Int main()
{
Sum();
Return 0;
}
Public int sum()
{
Int a,b,c;
a=10;
b=10;
Return c=a+b;
}
```

I want sum method to be run in the background as process continuously. How can i run c program as process? If this is not possible is there any alternative methods to achieve above task? 
Later on I want to access this process from c#. 
Any  help on this greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: That's not C. It might look similar to C, but it's not actually C.

Comment: This doesn't make sense - this function (and this whole program) does a single calculation and then ends.  What would it mean to "run it continuously"?

Comment: 1. C is CASE SENSITIVE
2. Your Sum function does stuff, but are you receiving its return value?
3. CASE SENSITIVE!! Hurts my eyes

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I typed from my mobile. Please do not consider Syntex.

Comment: Even if your mobile capitalizes words, Public has nothing to do with C syntax

Comment: Sorry. I am c# developer. Just trying hands on with c.

Comment: If you want to run a C program as a background process, maybe you should let us see the actual C program.

Answer (score 1):

Running a job in the background has nothing to do with the language it was written in.  To run any program (assuming a bourne shell like syntax) you run it like

```
sh>./program &
```

the '&' tells the shell to execute it backgrounded.  The program will do whatever it does and if the end of main()is reached or it calls exit() the job will finish.  The life-cycle of a job is basically the same when in the foreground or background.

Probably what you actually want is to learn how to write a [daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)).

[Here](https://github.com/jirihnidek/daemon) is a simple example.

Comment: Hi thanks. I m using VI editor. So I should not stop the adding two numbers job right?